# MySQL Trigger to PostgreSQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a trigger in MySQL written as such:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger 
BEFORE INSERT ON people
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

   SET NEW.first_name  = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( NEW.name, ' ', 1), ' ', -1);

   SET NEW.last_name   = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( NEW.name, ' ', 3), ' ', -1);

   SET NEW.middle_name = IF(LENGTH( NEW.name) - LENGTH(REPLACE( NEW.name, ' ', ''))>1
       ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( NEW.name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1)
       ,NULL);

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I'm switching to PostgreSQL since Heroku's ClearDB option for MySQL requires a plan costing inordinate amounts of money to use triggers

My question is: I've tried everything, how can I get this trigger to work in PostgreSQL?

Comment: "*I've tried everything*" - what exactly _have_ you tried?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've tried creating this same trigger in Postgres, using the same info listed above from `SET NEW.first_name...` to `SET NEW.middle_name...` Postgres will recognize this as valid syntax simply as a trigger, but when I try to access it in my application I get a lot of `unknown function`, then switched `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to `SPLIT_PART` and then a whole new set of errors comes up.

Comment: The assignment operator is `:=` in PL/pgSQL, not `SET`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name for leading me in the right direction though! Some of your other comments on similar questions helped a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating my PostgreSQL DB with https://github.com/pornel/mysqlcompat. I was able to successfully and correctly reformat my trigger to look as such:

The trigger function looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION name_split()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$BEGIN
NEW.first_name  := SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.name, ' ', 1), ' ', -1);
NEW.last_name   := IF(LENGTH( NEW.name) - LENGTH(REPLACE( NEW.name, ' ', ''))>1
       ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( NEW.name, ' ', 3), ' ', -3)
       ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( NEW.name, ' ', 3), ' ', -2));
NEW.middle_name := IF(LENGTH( NEW.name) - LENGTH(REPLACE( NEW.name, ' ', ''))>1
       ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( NEW.name, ' ', 2), ' ', -2)
       ,NULL);
RETURN NEW;
END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

And the actual trigger reads:

```
CREATE TRIGGER split
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON actors
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE name_split();
```

Comment: The key was using https://github.com/pornel/mysqlcompat so my PostgreSQL DB could understand `substring_index` and `if`, among other functions. From there it just took minor tweaking to get it working correctly